# Disable storing tracebacks on error

Tags: r, error-handling, traceback

Is there a way to disable the storing of tracebacks on error in R temporarily (for a session)?

The reason I ask is that ggplot2 has a [long-running problem](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/876), that they've been unable to fix. Somehow the entire dataset gets stored in the traceback, and if you work with very large datasets, this means that a mis-typed variable name can leave you with a 10-minute hang.

Especially when I make complex plots for very large data, this is crippling. Usually these are all small typos, I don't ever need tracebacks, just the error message would be fine.

I tried

```
options(error = expression(NULL))
```

but apparently that handler is called after the traceback is stored (the hang persists).

### reproducible example

```
library(ggplot2)
data(diamonds)
diamonds = diamonds[sample(x=nrow(diamonds),size=200000,replace=T),]
qplot(data=diamonds, wrong, var)
```

Comment: I don't know (and will be surprised when someone shows how to do this), but generic advice when dealing with larger data applies here. Write and test the plotting code with a smaller sample of the data. And if you use the `stat_*` functions for aggregation, try to do that outside of ggplot2 instead.

Comment: @Roland Yeah, but no. That's the thing with typos. I just make one change to my plotting code, swapping out the variable or so, and of course I don't use a sample of the data for that, because 9 times out of 10 I won't make a typo. But yeah it may not be doable. A fix for this annoying problem in ggplot would be even better of course, but if Hadley can't do it...

Comment: I wonder what a 'minimal reproducible example' is (without using ggplot2, just base R commands)? Not that it hangs forever, but that it triggers traceback() with data-that-could-be-large.

Comment: @MartinMorgan Haven't been able to generate one yet, but if you look at the github comment thread you'll see it only crops up when using quoted expressions and that the traceback goes to eval via plyr::eval.quoted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One obvious thing that I hadn't thought about is to wrap the call in `tryCatch`, like this:

```
tryCatch({
    print(qplot(data=diamonds, wrong, var))
}, error = function(e){warning(e)})
```

It's important to print your plot *inside* the tryCatch, as otherwise the error occurs once the returned plot object is automatically printed.

I would still be interested in the reverse equivalent of `options(warn=2)` (i.e. instead of turning warnings into errors so that they can be traced, it would turn errors into warnings, so they don't generate a huge traceback).